# Using Rails to build a frontend for an API (the MVC "model" is an external API not a database)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-frontend

I see plenty of articles, posts, and videos about using Rails to build an API-only back-end that is consumed by a various possible front-end technologies (React, Angular, Vue, etc.).

However if one of the desired front-end apps is a separate, standalone *front-end* for the API built with Rails, are there any tools, gems, or techniques that facilitate creating a "regular" Rails MVC app except, I suppose, the controller CRUD actions replace ActiveRecord with API calls?

One use case example might be that web and mobile front-ends used by *consumers* will use Vue.js or React. But an entirely separate "managers" front-end app is quicker to develop and easier to maintain using Rails, while still strictly enforcing back-end / front-end separation.

Comment: Not sure I understand your qestion. Rails has a view layer (actionview) with a bunch of helpers that help you build html on the server. In recent years it add turbolinks and really recently hotwire https://hotwire.dev/

Comment: I worked on a project that did this and would not recommend it as a solution. It gets clunky very fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [ActiveResource](https://github.com/rails/activeresource). According to the Overview:

> Model classes are mapped to remote REST resources by Active Resource much the same way Active Record maps model classes to database tables. When a request is made to a remote resource, a REST JSON request is generated, transmitted, and the result received and serialized into a usable Ruby object.

I gave ActiveResource a go many moons ago. In the end, I rolled my own.

Comment: It looks promising @jvillian, thank you... may I ask what factors made you decide to eventually roll your own?